# Order options in admin order view

Tags: magento

Using

```
public function _prepareOptions(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)
{
    $options = parent::_prepareOptions($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);
    $options['start_date'] = date here
    $options['end_date'] = date here
    return $options;
}
```

in my module I can save some custom options.
I can see them in the "sales_flat_quote_item_option" table.

What i'm stuck on is trying to retrieve and display these values with the order in the admin in this template

```
"app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\items\column\name.phtml"
```

Is there a way to get these options via the $_item variable in the template or will i need to use the orderid and models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure which is the correct way but used the buyRequest object

```
public function prepareForCartAdvanced(Varien_Object $buyRequest, $product = null, $processMode = null)
{
    $buyRequest->setData('start_date', $start);
}
```

Then in the view,

```
$_item->getBuyRequest()->getData('start_date');
```